# how to include <Nav/> Component in all other pages without writing it multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, rendering

I want to display my navbar in all other router pages, but without writing `<Nav/>` many times because it will lead to rendering the same component many times.
my router:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/Login" element={<Signup />} />
    <Route path="/Login/Signin" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/Trend" element={<Search_Page />} />
    <Route path="/Popular" element={<Popular />} />
    <Route path="/Watch" element={<Watchingpage />} />
    <Route path="/Favorite" element={<Favorite />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIXMk.png)

The problem has been solved if I include the component in all other pages but it's not efficient at all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRQDa.png)

The problem with this is that it's including `<Nav/>` in `<Login/>` & `<SignUp/>`, Which I don't want to.